# Can't use multiple user in one login

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, jdbc, resultset

Ive got 2 database in my mysql db, when im entering the first row which is the "username" and the password is "password" it is going accordingly. But when im entering the second row, it says incorrect password

Here is my code:

```
public void tlogin() {
    String u,p;
    try {
        String username,password;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/subject_db","root","");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM teacher_login");
        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("Enter Username: ");
            u =new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
            p =new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
            while(!(u.equals(username = rs.getString(2))&&p.equals(password = rs.getString(3)))) {
                System.out.println("Incorrect Login!");
                System.out.println("Enter Username: ");
                u =new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
                p =new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
            }
            System.out.println("Correct Login!");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            thome();
        }
        con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean ive got 2 data in my database

Comment: Your workflow is incorrect.  You should be obtaining the username and password first, _before_ you query, then you should query the user table to see if you can find a match.

Comment: You shouldn't store plain text passwords in a database. Use an appropriate password hash algorithm like pbkdf2 or bcrypt.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can u send me some example ?